# How to use SSH to authenticate an application?

Tags: authentication, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to create an MDM-esque application for Linux, where there is a server-side application that connects to the client-side application on another device. The server application sends some arbitrary message of an undecided format containing configuration rules to the client. For security, the client device of course needs to verify the message comes from the server and has not been modified.

I would like to have the applications communicate using SSH if possible. I know applications such as git, rsync, and a couple others have verification via SSH set-up, and this to me seems like the most ergonomic and not "roll your own crypto" way to achieve this task. Let's say on the client end, there is a user named "user1" that is running a daemonized version of the client app.

One way I thought about doing this is using ssh tunneling, but for that to be secure, I would need to set up a bunch of firewall rules on the client device to make sure that a) no arbitrary device can connect to the application port (lets say 5555), and b) a non-privileged user on the client device can't send a packet leading to a privilege escalation. While it seems it is possible to do this using firewall rules, it seems like some random admin messing around with the firewall on a device could cause more damage than they anticipated, and, to my knowledge, applications like rsync do not seem to rely on blocking ports to ensure that a port is only accessed via ssh, so I imagine there is a better way.

Does anyone know of a better way to handle this?

Comment: I have no idea about your application but I am wondering if what you are looking for is not client certificates.

Comment: Not quite. Essentially, I want to leverage SSHs built in authentication and encryption to create a tunnel to send a custom payload to a client server. Kind of like using SSH as a pseudo transport layer protocol.

Comment: In SSH, it's the client that connects to the server, not the other way round. And if you're rolling out this solution on multiple devices, you'll have to think about password or key management. If the purpose is to retrieve configuration rules, I guess a basic API running on an https endpoint with a trusted server certificate (eg Let's encrypt or self-signed) of some sort is appropriate. And you can throw in a client certificate for mutual authentication. Makes sense?

Comment: I was planning on having a sort of inverted relationship where the client had an SSH server open, and the server application would connect to that to dispatch commands.

Comment: There is reverse SSH, and it can be used to set up persistent SSH tunnels. But I am convinced a simple API as a command & control would do the job. Besides, port 443 is almost always available. Now, if you're looking for some persistent connectivity, you could set up a VPN server instead, and configure the clients to connect as soon as there is Internet access. Then you have an encrypted tunnel which is more convenient than plain SSH.